# Converting a SELECT with 2 JOINS and a COUNT into an UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm sort of throwing a hail mary here after going crazy trying to figure out how to write this correctly. I've searched near and far and haven't found something that made this "click" for me yet.

Here's the situation:  There's 3 tables (columns involved in parens):

- prods (prod_id PK, prod_grp_id)
- prod_grps (prod_grp_id PK, prod_grp_mgr_nm)
- prod_grp_prods (prod_id, prod_grp_id)

A product can belong to more than one prod_grp.  For instance, a baseball can be in the sports prod_grp, which may have prod_grp_mgr_nm = "AssMGR_Bill" while also being in the general_merch group with prod_grp_mgr_nm = "LeadMGR_Jake".  I need to go through every item in the prods table and update the "prod_grp_id" value for each item so that it contains the prod_group_id managed by someone with "LeadMGR" in their prod_grp_mgr_nm.  I want to update prods only when there's just one prod_grp with prod_grp_mgr_nm containing "LeadMGR".  The goal here is to associate each prod with a group managed by a lead manager if one (and only one) exists.

So far, I've got this SELECT statement:

```
    SELECT prods.prod_id
    FROM prods p
    INNER JOIN prod_grp_prods pgp
    ON prod.prod_id = pgp.prod_id
    INNER JOIN prod_grps pg
    ON pgp.prod_grp_id = pg.acct_grp_id
    WHERE pg.prod_grp_mgr_nm LIKE '%LeadMGR%'
    GROUP BY p.prod_id HAVING COUNT(p.prod_id) = 1
    ORDER BY p.prod_id`
```

This returns all the prod_ids needing updating.

Comment: Ever heard of SQLFiddle? VERY HELPFUL... especially for testing collaboratively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your questions with below queries. I used subquery to update prods table. I hope this does replicate your issues.

```
create table #prods (prod_id int PRIMARY KEY, prod_grp_id int)
create table #prod_grps (acct_grp_id int PRIMARY KEY, prod_grp_mgr_nm varchar(200))
create table #prod_grp_prods (prod_id int , prod_grp_id int)

-- insert testing data
insert into #prods values (1, null), (2,null), (3, null)
insert into #prod_grps values (999, 'AssMGR_Bill'), (998, 'LeadMGR_Jake'), (995, 'LeadMGR_Jake')
insert into #prod_grp_prods values (1, 999), (2, 995), (3, 999), (1,998)

-- original query
SELECT p.prod_id, pgp.prod_grp_id
    FROM #prods p
    INNER JOIN #prod_grp_prods pgp
    ON p.prod_id = pgp.prod_id
    INNER JOIN #prod_grps pg
    ON pgp.prod_grp_id = pg.acct_grp_id
    WHERE pg.prod_grp_mgr_nm LIKE '%LeadMGR%'
    GROUP BY p.prod_id , pgp.prod_grp_id
    HAVING COUNT(p.prod_id) = 1
    ORDER BY p.prod_id

-- update query
update #prods set prod_grp_id = t.prod_grp_id
from 
(
  SELECT p.prod_id, pgp.prod_grp_id
    FROM #prods p
    INNER JOIN #prod_grp_prods pgp
    ON p.prod_id = pgp.prod_id
    INNER JOIN #prod_grps pg
    ON pgp.prod_grp_id = pg.acct_grp_id
    WHERE pg.prod_grp_mgr_nm LIKE '%LeadMGR%'
    GROUP BY p.prod_id , pgp.prod_grp_id
    HAVING COUNT(p.prod_id) = 1

)t  
where t.prod_id = #prods.prod_id

-- view results
select * from #prods
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will solve your fundamental problem.

```
alter table prods
drop column prod_grp_id
```

As you described, there is a many to many relationship between products and groups.  You also have table prod_grp_prods to implement that relationship.  Having a group id field in your product table is quite simply, a bad idea.

**Edit starts here**

Here is a bandaid solution

```
update p
set prod_grp_id = pgp.prod_grp_id
from prods p join prod_grp_prods pgp on p.prod_id = pgp.prod_id
join (
select prod_id, count(*) records
from prod_grp_prods 
group by prod_id
having count(*) = 1) temp on temp.prod_id = p.prod_id
```

You'll need another query to nullify the other records.

Comment: That's no joke, but unfortunately I'm not in the position to make a change like that, as there's a lot of legacy stuff that would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE prods
 SET    prod_grp_id = BS.prod_grp_id
 FROM   (
          SELECT prods.prod_id,
                 pgp.prod_grp_id

          FROM   prods p 

                 INNER JOIN prod_grp_prods pgp ON 
                 prod.prod_id = pgp.prod_id 

                 INNER JOIN prod_grps pg ON 
                 pgp.prod_grp_id = pg.acct_grp_id 

          WHERE  pg.prod_grp_mgr_nm LIKE '%LeadMGR%' 

          GROUP BY 
                 p.prod_id,
                 pgp.prod_grp_id 

          HAVING COUNT(p.prod_id) = 1 
     ) BS

  WHERE prods.prod_id = BS.prod_id
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this, but got a "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'prod_grp_prods.prod_grp_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." message.  I was running into this issue when trying to build my own UPDATE statement originally as well.